# what to learn for layout design? DIV+css or the new CSS3 GRID 2D layput?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am a newbie who wants to learn layout design in html.

From what I learned is that one should use DIV and css styles for this.

But while I was searching, I found about the new draft of CSS3 2D grid layout:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/

> This CSS module defines a two-dimensional  grid-based layout system,
>   optimized for user interface design

and

> It excels at dividing up space for major regions of an application,
>   or defining the relationship in terms of size, position, and layer
>   between parts of a control built from HTML primitives

From looking at it and the diagrams they have there, it seems to be better for layout design.

Has anyone used this and can suggest if one should spend time to learn this new 2D grid rather than spend the time to learn using DIV for layout design purpose? Again, I am very new to HTML and trying to ask to choose the right thing to study.

**add**

There is also CSS Grid Template Layout Module http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-template/

> This draft combines ideas from earlier drafts on Template Layout, Grid
>   Positioning [CSS3GRID] and Grid Layout [CSS3-GRID-LAYOUT].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This feature is still in draft status. That means that there isn't even a finalized standard for it yet. The draft can change at any time, so it would be crazy for anyone to use it. According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid), the only browser which supports it is Internet Explorer 10 and 11.

Until a feature is widely-adopted by all web browsers in common use you shouldn't use it. This could take years, so you should rather learn the conventional css-positioning for now.

**Update:** 4 years later, most browsers support grid layout, so it became a viable tool for web development. But there are still a few exceptions which might warrant putting some work into making sure that your application is at least not completely unusable without grid layout support. Also keep in mind that both grid layout and the "classic" way of div positioning are *tools*. Use the right tool for each job. The existence of grid layout is no excuse for refusing to learn about the other layout techniques.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is draft. I just did not think it will be years before one can use it. I thought it will be few months or so. From what I read, HTML5 itself is not officially complete and finalized, yet many are using it. But I see your point. If it will take years, then I better just learn Div+css for now for layout design.

Comment: According to Philipp's great link only ~5% of users globally at this time would be able to see a web page made with the CSS grid layout. Based upon past experience, this is unlikely to even 25% within 1 year. So it is definitely advisable to consider it a feature that might never become accepted or be usable by most browsers within 5 years.